# For a lie group $G$ with bi-invariant metric, and left-invariant fields $X,U,V$, $\langle [U,X],V\rangle = -\langle U,[V,X]\rangle$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Specifically, I'm somewhat confused by the answer to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669127/show-that-langleu-x-v-rangle-langle-u-v-x-rangle-for-bi-invariant-met), which I reproduce below:

> Let $g$ denote the metric of $G$. The right invariance of $g$ guarantees that
>   $$R^*_{\exp (tX)}g=g,  \forall t \in \mathbb{R}. $$
>   On the other hand, $t\to R_{exp(tX)}$ is the flow of X, we have $\mathcal{L}_Xg=0$, where $\mathcal{L}_Xg$ denotes the Lie derivative of $g$ in the direction X. 
>   $$(\mathcal{L}_Xg)(U,V)=X(g(U,V))-g(\mathcal{L}_XU,V)-g(U,\mathcal{L}_YZ) \\ =-\langle[X,U],V\rangle-\langle U,[X,V]\rangle$$
>
> where we use the invariance of $g$ at last equal to conclude that $g(U,V)$, seen as function of $G$, is constant in each connected component of $G$.

My question is, why can we assume that $\mathcal{L}_X g = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a vector field $X$ with flow $\varphi_t^X$, the definition of the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_X g$ is

$$ \mathcal{L}_X g = \frac{d}{dt} (\varphi_t^X)^{*}(g)|_{t = 0}. $$

In your case, $\varphi_t^X = R_{\exp(tX)}$ and the second line shows that $R_{\exp(tX)}^{*}g$ is constant (doesn't depend on $t$) so the derivative with respect to $t$ is zero.